# Golang close net listener

Tags: go, proxy, listener, goroutine

I am having trouble closing a listener so that I can reopen it on the same port. I am writing a proxy server that is hot-configurable - i.e what it does (redirects/blocks etc) can be adjusted on the fly. The proxy runs in a go routine. The problem I am having is when I reconfigure the listener and proxy the listener is still using that port from the previous configuration. (FYI listener is a global pointer)
I'm trying something like:

to kill the listener:

```
func KillProxy() {
    
    if listener != nil {
        log.Println(" *** TRYING TO STOP THE PROXY SERVER")
        (*listener).Close()
        listener = nil
    }
}
```

before reconfiguring it like:

```
log.Println("listener (S1): ", listener)
if listener == nil {
    // Start the listener to listen on the connection.
    l, err := net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST + ":" + CONN_PORT)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error here: ", err)
    }    
    listener = &l //set it as a pointer to the newly created listener
} 
log.Println("listener (S2): ", listener)
```

however that doesnt seem to work - I get the error:

> listener (S1):
>
> error here:  listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use
>
> listener (S2): 0xc2080015e0

and then a massive stack trace that summizes to:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO JIM:

Interesting re pointers. OK. I am not handling waiting for the socket to close, Im not sure how that should be done. The proxy library I am using is this one: https://github.com/abourget/goproxy. The order things happen is:

```
KillProxy()
refreshProxy()
```

refreshProxy holds the code posted above that tries to repurpose the listener. The last thing that happens in `refreshProxy()` is:

`go http.Serve(*listener, proxy)`

So if I revert to listener being a global variable, not a pointer I can make KillProxy():

```
func KillProxy() {
    if listener != nil {
        listener.Close()
        listener = nil
    }
}
```

and then setup the listener again as

```
listener, err := net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST + ":" + CONN_PORT) 
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error here: ", err)
    }
```

However I don't know how to wait and check whether the socket has closed before trying to re create the listener object?

Comment: Never use a pointer to an interface, it's only confusing the issue and probably related to your panic. If the port is bound, then you're not waiting for the socket to close before binding again. Please show the actual code handling that.

Comment: I don't think you should use `l` if `err != nil`. I don't remember what the conventions are, but I could imagine it's just garbage.

Comment: @JimB I have edited my original post.

Comment: You have to handle the closing socket around the accept loop, so check for the error retuned by http.Serve. Also, don't set the listener to nil (try running with the race detector)

Comment: @JimB OK I can test against the .Serve, but if it errors, do I put a delay in or something and call it again? Ok will remove `listener = nil` in KillProxy(). Sorry whats the race detector? Do you know of an example of this?

Answer (score -1):

Ok this is far from perfect, but the only way I found of not having it error out on me was to artifically put a delay in my code so the socket had time to close.
This isn't great as it means the proxy is down for 2 seconds while the socket closes, but at least it doesnt error out. 
If someone has a better solution I would like to hear it

```
func KillProxy() {
    if listener != nil {
        listener.Close()
        log.Println("waiting for socket to close")
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a sleep is the worst way to coordinate concurrency, especially since there's still no guarantee it won't panic. You need to wait for http.Serve to return, then start a new listener.

Comment: Yeah I've fixed this properly now without delays. I now have a struct that wraps around a listener and handles closing itself. Took a while to crack, but got there in the end